# How do I level up in Ars Magica 2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I've been playing [Ars Magica 2](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/2028696-ars-magica-2-164-version-110-updated-dec-22/#entry24949311) and casting spells but there's no xp bar for the magic.  I have checked the options but that's not it, I can move it but can't see it.  I'm also not levelling - I've killed like 20 mobs with just magic and I'm still level 1 with 100 mana and like 11 burnout.  Ars Magica is a Minecraft mod and is part of some of the Feed the Beast packs for 1.6.4 and i can cast the spells

Comment: Is this a Minecraft mod or another game entirely?  Either way, could you provide a link to a website or wiki?

Comment: yes its a mine craft modhttp://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/2028696-ars-magica-2-164-version-110-updated-dec-22/     hope this is what people need to help. i really need to take a computer class lol

Answer (score 0):

it appears as if there is currently a bug that doesn't grant XP for projectile spells. I have no idea if Mythion has been made aware of this or if he has planned it this way.